# Присвоить id по клику на div?

Tags: javascript

Как присвоить id="myshowcolor" по клику на div, а input, который находится выше присвоить id="myhexcode"?

Я нашел что-то приблизительное в интернете, но вот переделать мозгов не хватает.

```
$("#tabs").on("click", ".tab", function(){
    $("#tabs .tab").removeClass("active"); //удаляем класс во всех вкладках
    $(this).addClass("active"); //добавляем класс текущей (нажатой)
});
```

Пример структуры:

```
<input>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
<div></div>
</a>

<input>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
<div></div>
</a>

<input>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
<div></div>
</a>

<input>
<a href="javascript:void(0);">
<div></div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div').click(function(event) {
  //Удаляем старые id
  $('#myhexcode').attr('id', null);
  $('#myshowcolor').attr('id', null);

  //Ставим новые
  $(this).parent().prev().attr('id', 'myhexcode');
  $(this).attr('id', 'myshowcolor'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать функцию attr (https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Примерно так:

```
$("#tabs").on("click", ".tab", function(){
    $(this).attr("id", "some-id");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').on('click', function(){ 
    $(this).parent().attr('id', 'myshowcolor'); 
    $(this).siblings('input:first').attr('id', 'myhexcode'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var $div = $(this).find('div')[0];
    var $input = $(this).prev()[0];
    $($div).attr('id', 'myshowcolor');
    $($input).attr('id', 'myhexcode');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Поменять id элемента:

```
$(this).attr("id","newId");
```

Или ещё проще:

```
this.id = "newId";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').click(function(){
  $(this).attr('id', 'myshowcolor');
  $(this).closest('input').attr('id', 'myhexcode');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа

```
$(document).on('click', 'a > div', function() {
    $(this)
        .parent().prop('id', 'myshowcolor')
        .prev('input').prop('id', 'myhexcode')
    ;
});
```

[Демо](http://jsfiddle.net/ssquqsf9/)

Answer (score 0):

Можно так например:

```
$('div').on('click', function () {
    $(this).attr('id', 'myshowcolor'); // Добавляем атрибут id для текущего div
    $(this).parent().prev().attr('id', 'myhexcode'); // Добавляем атрибут id для текущего input
});
```

Это для вашей разметки, чтобы работало везде, нужно придумать более логичную структуру, незавимисую от тегов, а привязаться, к классам например.